# Padrino app with ActiveRecord+MySQL running out of memory running on nginx and passenger

Tags: memory, nginx, sinatra, padrino

Killing and restarting nginx solved the problem.

My question is, where do I start looking? What could be common causes of such a stack running out of memory?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, maybe there is some where a "loop" ?

Comment: I will look at the code + the logs. Thank you for the suggestion.